# Pure-FTPd Symlink won't work

Tags: pure-ftpd

Okay, So I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I Installed Pure-FTPd
I made a user and group for it
When I log in with a FTP client it puts me in /home/group/user

I want to have access to my Storage drive from there so I put a symlink in the folder
that points to /media/Store and it shows up on the FTP, but, It won't let me follow it.

The /media/Store drive is formated in NTFS so I cannot change permissions on it.

etc/pure-ftpd/conf has:

```
AltLog clf:/

ChrootEveryone yes

Daemonize yes

FSCharset UTF-8

MaxClientsNumber 50

MaxClientsPerIP 2

MinUID 1000

NoAnonymous yes

PAMAuthentication no

PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb

TrustedGID 1001

UnixAuthentication no
```

my pureftpd.passwd file looks almost like

```
user:x:1001:1001:://usr/group/user/::::::::::::
```

my etc/default/pure-ftpd-common looks like

```
# Configuration for pure-ftpd
# (this file is sourced by /bin/sh, edit accordingly)
# STANDALONE_OR_INETD
# valid values are "standalone" and "inetd".
# Any change here overrides the setting in debconf.
STANDALONE_OR_INETD=standalone
# VIRTUALCHROOT: 
# whether to use binary with virtualchroot support
# valid values are "true" or "false"
# Any change here overrides the setting in debconf.
VIRTUALCHROOT=true
# UPLOADSCRIPT: if this is set and the daemon is run in standalone mode,
# pure-uploadscript will also be run to spawn the program given below
# for handling uploads. see /usr/share/doc/pure-ftpd/README.gz or
# pure-uploadscript(8)
# example: UPLOADSCRIPT=/usr/local/sbin/uploadhandler.pl
UPLOADSCRIPT=
# if set, pure-uploadscript will spawn $UPLOADSCRIPT running as the
# given uid and gid
UPLOADUID=
UPLOADGID=
```

I've tried different configurations but can't get out of the login folder and into the Storage Drive
I'm probably just missing something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I spun up a VirtualBox guest to try this out with:

- 8GB VDI, 512MB RAM
- Install from ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
- /dev/sda1, 7000MB, ext4, mount /
- /dev/sda5, 999MB, fat32, mount /media/Store (NTFS wasn't an option in the installer)
- /dev/sda6, 587MB, swap
- All other settings default except for time zone.

Ack, I'd forgotten how awful Unity was. :) I added Virtual Guest Additions, ran `update-manager`, waited for... 618 updates, reboot. Then I followed the Community documentation at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP

```
sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd
    # already installed?
gksudo gedit /etc/inetd.conf
    # no changes required?
gksudo gedit  /etc/default/pure-ftpd-common
    # already: STANDALONE_OR_INETD=standalone
    # changed: VIRTUALCHROOT=true
sudo groupadd ftpgroup
sudo useradd -g ftpgroup -d /dev/null -s /etc ftpuser
```

NOTE: `id ftpuser` returns `uid=1001(ftpuser) gid=1001(ftpgroup) groups=1001(ftpgroup)` at this point.

```
sudo mkdir /home/ftpusers
sudo mkdir /home/ftpusers/joe
sudo pure-pw useradd joe -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/joe
sudo pure-pw mkdb
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd /etc/pureftpd.passwd
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb /etc/pureftpd.pdb
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/PureDB
sudo sh -c 'echo "no" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/UnixAuthentication'
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpgroup -R /home/ftpusers
gksudo pureadmin
```

Confirmed that `/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd` contained:

```
joe:...:1001:1001::/home/ftpusers/joe/./::::::::::::

sudo /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
    # Restarting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-virtualchroot -l pam -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb -E -8 UTF-8 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -u 1000 -B
```

Now I was able to `ftp localhost` as joe.

First attempt: I created a symlink to /media/Store, which joe could see in his `ls /`, but could not `cd` in to (550 Can't change directory to Store: Permission denied):

```
sudo ln -s /media/Store /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpgroup -R /home/ftpusers/joe
    # sudo rm /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
```

Second attempt: I created a symlink to /dev/sda5, which joe could see in his `ls /`, but could not `cd` in to (550 Can't change directory to Store: Not a directory):

```
sudo ln -s /dev/sda5 /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpgroup -R /home/ftpusers/joe
    # sudo rm /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
```

This wasn't surpising, since /dev/sda5 is a block store not a file system, but I tried it for giggles.

Third attempt: Being the alternative that I gave in my first answer, worked:

```
sudo mkdir /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpgroup -R /home/ftpusers/joe
sudo mount -t vfat -o noexec,ro,uid=1001,gid=1001 /dev/sda5 /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
```

NOTE: I had to `sudo umount /media/Store` before I could mount it at /home/ftpusers/joe/Store.

To be doubly sure that this also works with NTFS, I `sudo umount /home/ftpusers/joe/Store`, I ran Disk Utility, reformatted the partition as NTFS, mounted the volume (which opens it in Nautilus), added a HelloNtfsWorld.txt file, unmounted it in Disk Utility, then the above test with the slightly modified `mount` command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o noexec,ro,uid=1001,gid=1001 /dev/sda5 /home/ftpusers/joe/Store
```

Perfect!

```
ftp> ls -la
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 53727
drwxr-xr-x    3 1001       ftpgroup         4096 Sep 15 22:12 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 1001       ftpgroup         4096 Sep 15 22:12 ..
drwxrwxrwx    1 1001       ftpgroup         4096 Sep 15 22:36 Store
226-Options: -a -l 
226 3 matches total
ftp> cd Store
250 OK. Current directory is /Store
ftp> ls -la
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 57505
drwxrwxrwx    1 1001       ftpgroup         4096 Sep 15 22:36 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 1001       ftpgroup         4096 Sep 15 22:12 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1001       ftpgroup            0 Sep 15 22:36 HelloNtfsWorld.txt
226-Options: -a -l 
226 3 matches total
ftp>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Pure-FTPd FAQ yet? http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ

Unfortunately symlinks (that point outside the FTP user's chroot folder) are not supported unless you build from source using the --with-virtualchroot switch.

Alternatively you can change the mount point of the storage drive from /media/Store to somewhere inside your FTP folder hierarchy, but this will cause it to disappear from Nautilus's drives list.

Comment: Yes, I've read the Pure-FTPd FAQ but it isn't exactly accurate
several of the features that it "claims" are not supported unless you build from source seem to be functional in the build I Installed from terminal.

The virtualchroot may be an exception so I may need to uninstall and build from source (feel free to point me to a tutorial on how to do that.) However, I wanted to make sure it wasn't a configuration issue before doing that.

I don't want to change the mount point of the Storage Drive because I already mapped out several links to it in lots of software like Gimp and such.

Comment: Although it says in the FAQ that you need to build from source using --with-virtualroot switch it also says...

FYI, the binary RPM packages of Pure-FTPd are configured with the following
command line:

./configure --with-everything --with-paranoidmsg --without-capabilities \
            --with-virtualchroot

RPM packages are also compiled with --without-pam to enhance their
portability.

and supposedly the one I installed was built this way.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it

I used gksu PureAdmin to Edit User and Group ID.
User ID now matches my Admin login Name for Ubuntu
Group ID is now adm

uid=1000 gid=4

now I can follow the symlink

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is to install PureAdmin (which is a GUI for Pure-FTPd) from the software center but then it is important you read this: http://helloinfinity.com/pure-ftpd-authentication-failed-in-ubuntu/

So the commands to be run afterwards are:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/50pure
```

`sudo vi /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/MinUID` (change value to a figure below 1000, such as 100 for example)

```
sudo service pure-ftpd restart
```